# Modules in ruby with Concern - DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, dry

I have a controllor named Activities in my Rails Project, with included this Module 'Sortable':

Controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController

  include Sortable
  ...
```

Module(Working):

```
module Sortable
  def save_positions
    @ids = params[:ids]
    # ~ Converting to array separating by ',' 
    @ids = @ids.split(",")

    count = 0
    # ~ Saving new positions
    for i in @ids
      Activity.update(i, {:position => count})
      count += 1
    end

    render :json => :success
  end
end
```

But when I refactor code for I can use with others Controllers:

EDITED

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Sortable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module InstanceMethods
    def save_positions
      @ids = params[:ids]
      # ~ Converting to array separating by ',' 
      @ids = @ids.split(",")

      count = 0
      # ~ Saving new positions
      for i in @ids
        update(i, {:position => count})
        count += 1
      end

      render :json => :success
    end
  end
end
```

What I doing wrong?

New Error Msg:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)): app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:61:in
```

I removed 'Activity' from:

```
Activity.update(i, {:position => count})
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller actions are implemented as instance methods on a controller, not class methods.  You've got everything set up perfectly fine from what I can see, other than the fact that you've defined `save_positions` as a class method and not an instance method.

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Sortable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module InstanceMethods ## <== just changed this
    def save_positions
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**Updating to answer the next part of the question:**

You're trying to call a method on a model from a shared controller action.  You can't know what that model is ahead of time.  If you *really* want to keep your code shared in the controllers and not the models, we can figure out the model at runtime and make things work

The shared `save_positions` action:

```
def save_positions
  @ids = params[:ids]
  # ~ Converting to array separating by ',' 
  @ids = @ids.split(",")

  count = 0
  # ~ Saving new positions
  for i in @ids
    AR_CLASS.update(i, {:position => count})
    count += 1
  end

  render :json => :success
end
```

Some random controllers:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  include Sortable
  AR_CLASS = Activity
  # ....
end

class FoosController < ApplicationController
  include Sortable
  AR_CLASS = Foo
  # ....
end
```

Then, your `save_postition` action will call `update` on the right model depending on which controller it's run from.

Comment: This solved, but I'm with another erro on line `update(i, {:position => count})`  ... Error msg: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)):
  app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:61:in `update'`

Comment: I'm assuming your controller has resourceful routes - new, create, edit, update, etc...  So `update` is already the name of an action defined in your controller.  You'll have to rename _your_ update method to something else.  Also, you should mark my answer as the correct answer if it solved your original question.

Comment: No, It's to work like `Activity.update(i, {:position => count})` but I want to remove `Activity` to use with others Controllers too..

Comment: You'd have to dynamically figure out what model you want to call `update` on based on the controller you're in.  Not sure how you'd easily or cleanly go about doing that.  Maybe this logic belongs in the model instead of the controller?

Comment: Need to be in controller, because save_position is an action and returns json result... :(

Comment: Added a wacky idea to my answer.